# node js require executing function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I cant get the function to execute. When I run `node app.js` in the terminal I get `[Function: hi]`.

I have two files

app.js

```
var show = require('./code');
console.log(show.hi);
```

code.js

```
function hi() {
    console.log('I am inside function Hi');
}

module.exports.hi = hi;
```

if I will do something like this `console.log(show.hi())` then I will get

```
I am inside function Hi
undefined
```

Comment: You never call the function. `console.log(show.hi());`

Comment: this will show this in console "I am inside function Hi undefined". How to get rid of undefined?

Comment: Just use `show.hi();`

Comment: If your question has been answered by one of the answers, please indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the best answer.    That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.  If your question has not been fully answered yet, then please leave a comment on each answer for what it is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not calling the function.

Call it like

```
show.hi();
```

You're getting undefined because your `hi` function returns nothing. Remove `console.log` I mean just execute the function `show.hi()`

In short `console.log(show.hi);` should just be  `show.hi()`

Comment: this will show this in console "I am inside function Hi undefined". How to get rid of undefined?

Comment: remove `console.log`. You're getting undefined because function `hi` is not returning anything

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute your function, then do this:

```
var show = require('./code');
// get the `hi` property and call it as a function 
show.hi();
```

`show` is the module.exports object from the `code` module.  So, `show.hi` would be the `hi` property you assigned to the exports.  And, then to execute the function you must use `()` after it.

Comment: this will show this in console "I am inside function Hi undefined". How to get rid of undefined?

Comment: @AlexeyTseitlin - I don't think you implemented what I show in my answer.  Do not do `console.log(show.hi())`.  That logs `undefined` because `show.hi()` has no return value.  Do, it like I show in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing both the log `I am inside function Hi` and `undefined` is because `console.log` returns always `undefined` after its execution.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#return_value

(I stumbled on this question by chance and I thought that it needed a proper answer - while it's true that the question contain a typo and can be misleading)